# Does Matlab iphone sensor log have barometer data?

Tags: matlab

I see that they support accelerometer, gps, angular velocity etc but not barometer. Am I able to obtain the barometer data?

Answer (score 1):

Per their [website](http://ch.mathworks.com/hardware-support/iphone-sensor.html), barometer data cannot be (currently) acquired by Matlab Mobile. This would probably change in coming versions.